# Laravel 5.4 adding zurb foundation 6.3.0

Tags: laravel, webpack, zurb-foundation-6

i would like to learn the best way how to add zurb foundation single component to my fresh laravel project.

What i have done so far is:

```
npm install foundation-sites --save
```

And second is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" />
```

to my layout.blade.php

And my questions is what should i write in

1. **sass/app.scss**
2. **webpack.mix.js**

And maybe there is something else that needs to be done?
I want to use label component only...

```
<span class="label success">Hello world</span>
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

i solve that ,look at :

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/using-foundation-630-with-laravel-54

in **resources/assets/sass/app.scss**

add this after clear all what you find:

```
// Settings
@import "settings";

// Foundation
@import "node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation";

// Include Everything (True) for the Flex Grid :);
@include foundation-everything(true);
```

in `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`, look for `require('bootsrap-sass');` and remove it.

go to this path (**with File Explorer**) `node_modules\foundation-sites\scss\settings` and copy the file **_settings.scss**

to the new path 
**`resources\assets\sass`** , and you can remove the **_variables.scss** file.

**Open** the file **_settings.scss** in code editor , and change the **line 44**:

```
@import 'util/util';
```

to

```
@import "../../../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util";
```

**in webpack.mix.js**

open your file webpack.mix.js in the root of your project. and comment or remove the code:

change this:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

to this:

```
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
mix.combine([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation.min.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

**DO NOT FORGOT TO ADD the Initializing code to run JavaScript**

IN YOUR FOOTER:

```
<script> $(document).foundation();</script>
```